# What to do with answers to off-topic questions?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons, vote-to-close

I just found [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/330484/64248) question in the first posts review queue and voted to close it (see my comment to it) because I cannot see how U&L would benefit from it. Next, I found one of the answers in the review queue, and as I "feared", an opinion based discussion was already going on.

Independent from this case: When I think that a question is off-topic and I see an answer that confirms my view, then what should I do?

Answer (score 5):

Nothing. Just vote to close the question as off topic.

That said, I don't really see why that question is off topic. It basically boils down to: "Why does this *nix program behave in one way and this other *nix program behave in another way", so I'd call that on topic, myself.

Comment: Well, disagreement is part of the game, this is why more than one user votes. The question, however, was meant to ask for what to do with the _answer_ to off-topic questions.

Comment: @countermode absolutely, the second paragraph was just an afterthought. The first is the answer to your question: do nothing to the answer, just vote to close the question.